# How to get rid of DevExpress DXperience information screen

Tags: configuration, devexpress

I was tasked with making a change to an old application that makes use of DevExpress. I made the changes, and the application runs as expected, but an informational screen pops up on the screen when launching the application. I can just click 'x' to get rid of the screen, but I do not want end users to have to close this screen every time they launch the application. Does anyone have any insights regarding how to make this not show up? For example, is there a config setting I can add to make this not display?

I am also wondering if the information screen is showing up because I only have a trial version of DevExpress. We have not worked on the application for many years, and none of the developers that have worked on it have an active DevExpress license.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You literally answered your own question. You cannot build a production version of a program with the DevExpress trial. Furthermore, their EULA forbids you from even using a trial to build/develop applications outside of simple evaluation purposes. Per their EULA:

> You MAY NOT CREATE applications or begin software projects using the
> SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT PRODUCT(S) under the terms of the THIRTY (30) DAY
> EVALUATION (TRIAL) USE LICENSE.
>
> You MAY NOT REDISTRIBUTE files in the SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT PRODUCT(S)
> distribution if using an evaluation or trial version of the SOFTWARE
> DEVELOPMENT PRODUCT(S).

How did you get a copy of a 10+ year old trial installer? DevExpress does not offer outdated trial versions. There is no configuration setting you can change to prevent this screen from popping up. You need to have a license.licx file compiled into the application with a valid license.

If you purchase a license you will have access to previous versions, so you can buy the latest version and install the licensed 9.3.3.0 copy to compile your program without the trial box. You will need to purchase a license for every developer that works on this application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I got a 10 year old installer from our department archives, which we purchased back in the day when the app I am working on was developed. We did have a license because we were able to compile it back then without the info page coming up. After reading your post we called customer support and they helped us find who the license was assigned to, and then transfer the license to me since they don't use it any more.

Answer (score 0):

It says right there: you're using trial version, buy the license.